# Use Python 3 str.format to truncate a float to have no more than x number of digits

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am looking for an expression that will truncate a float to *at most* a certain number of digits.  I want to preserve a certain number of decimals, without having unnecessary trailing 0s.

So, this almost works as desired:

```
"{0:3.f"}.format(number)
```

For input 3.123000001:

```
"{0:.3f}".format(3.1230000001)
'3.123'
```

Great.  But for input 3:

```
"{0:.3f}".format(3)
'3.000'
```

Comment: I now agree that the question is duplicate, but I wasn't able to find the duplicate question when I spent ~5 minutes searching Google/stackoverflow looking for the answer.  Is that a sufficient reason to leave this question up, or should I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer while I was writing the question.  Just add `.rstrip('0')` to the expression.  So:

```
"{0:3.f}".format(number).rstrip('0')
```

Comment: your right quotation mark are in the wrong position .. also I guess it should be `rstrip` since you don't want to strip the leading 0 if it's between 0 and 1?

Comment: If you're happy with your own answer, you should accept it.

Comment: @Marvin, you can't accept your own answer for 2 days.

Comment: @KevinHe, correct on both counts, I was sloppy.  I've fixed both.